# AWS EMR HBase Bulk Load

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, amazon-emr, bulk-load

I developed a Map Reduce program to make HBase Bulk Loading using the technique explained in this Cloudera article : https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/.

On our previous on-prem Cloudera Hadoop cluster, it was working very well. Now, we are moving to AWS. I don't manage to make this program work on AWS EMR cluster.

EMR details :

- Release label:emr-5.16.0
- Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.4
- Applications:Spark 2.3.1, HBase 1.4.4
- Master : m4.4xlarge
- Nodes : 12 x m4.4xlarge

Here is the code of my Driver

```
        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
        job.setJobName("My job");
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());

        // Input
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, input);

        // Mapper
        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(ExampleInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);

        // Reducer : Auto configure partitioner and reducer
        Table table = HBaseCnx.getConnection().getTable(TABLE_NAME);
        RegionLocator regionLocator = HBaseCnx.getConnection().getRegionLocator(TABLE_NAME);
        HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table, regionLocator);

        // Output
        Path out = new Path(output);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        // Launch the MR job
        logger.debug("Start - Map Reduce job to produce HFiles");
        boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        if (!b) throw new RuntimeException("FAIL - Produce HFiles for HBase bulk load");
        logger.debug("End - Map Reduce job to produce HFiles");

        // Make the output HFiles usable by HBase (permissions)
        logger.debug("Start - Set the permissions for HBase in the output dir " + out.toString());
        //fs.setPermission(outputPath, new FsPermission(ALL, ALL, ALL)); => not recursive
        FsShell shell = new FsShell(getConf());
        shell.run(new String[]{"-chmod", "-R", "777", out.toString()});
        logger.debug("End - Set the permissions for HBase in the output dir " + out.toString());

        // Run complete bulk load
        logger.debug("Start - HBase Complete Bulk Load");
        LoadIncrementalHFiles loadIncrementalHFiles = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(getConf());
        int loadIncrementalHFilesOutput = loadIncrementalHFiles.run(new String[]{out.toString(), TABLE_NAME.toString()});
        if (loadIncrementalHFilesOutput != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Problem in LoadIncrementalHFiles. Return code is " + loadIncrementalHFiles);
        }
        logger.debug("End - HBase Complete Bulk Load");
```

My mapper reads Parquet files and emits :

- key which is the row key of a Put as ImmutableBytesWritable
- value which is a HBase Put

The issue happens in the Reduce step. In each Reducer's "syslog", I got errors that seem related to Socket connections. Here is a piece of syslog :

```
2018-09-04 08:21:39,085 INFO [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-09-04 08:21:39,086 WARN [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2018-09-04 08:21:55,705 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2018-09-04 08:21:55,705 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x3ecedf210x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
2018-09-04 08:21:55,706 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x3ecedf210x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
2018-09-04 08:21:55,706 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry: Can't retrieve clusterId from Zookeeper
```

After several search in Google, I found several posts that were advising to set the quorum IP directly in the Java code. I did that as well but it did not work. Here is how I currently get the HBase connection

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));

    // Attempts to set directly the quorum IP in the Java code that did not work
    //conf.clear();
    //conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "...ip...");
    //conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");

    Connection cnx = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
```

What I don't understand is that everything else is working. I can programmatically create tables, query the table (Scan or Get). I can even use a MR job that insert data with  `TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("my_table", IdentityTableReducer.class, job);`. But is of course much less fast than the HBase complete Bulk Load technique which directly writes HFiles splitted according to existing regions.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar migration. The issue is that the reducer runs in a separate process so you need to set the quorum on the job's configuration instead. That will make the value available to the reducer.

`job.getConfiguration().set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "...ip...");`